# Dokku Rails application missing static assets with 404 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dokku

I deployed a rails application with Dokku. Everything went fine except that all my assets including images returns a 404 error.

I really don't know how to debug this.

Answer (score 2):

For dokku it is simple to add:

`dokku config:set <your-app> RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true`

Answer (score 1):

I had exact same issue and adding the following gem solved it:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

That's the official way of dealing with that issue on Heroku for Rails 3 and 4 (and that gem is made by Heroku team as well).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I just added this :

```
config.serve_static_files = true
```

in environements/production.rb

[Note: flag deprecated in Rails 5.0 in in favor of `config.public_file_server.enabled`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#railties-deprecations)

Answer (score 0):

On rails 5, try making the changes  in production.rb that are suggested on this page [rails_12f](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor)